# setting an attribute at the class level to toggle logs on and off

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Basically during development I've found that printing messages to screen is super useful, but I don't always want all the mess.

Is there a good standard practice?

I was hoping to set an attribute on the class, and then manually toggle it on at the top of the junk code (using jupyter notebooks for playing around during development)

something like this, but it seems hacky

```
class testClass(object):
    printlogs = False
    def __init__(self):
        self.log('initialising')
        pass
    def log(self,text):
        if self.printlogs:
            print(text)
        pass


testClass.printlogs = True
t = testClass()
t.log('This will print')


testClass.printlogs = False
t2 = testClass()
t2.log('This will not')
```

Comment: This seems reasonable to me, if you want all instances of testClass to have the same value for `printLogs`, but you might want to check out the  [logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial). The logging module is designed exactly for this sort of use.

Comment: By the way, you only need to write `pass` if it's the _only_ line in a class or function definition (not including comments).

Comment: cool thanks. logging tutorial is super useful